# Объясните , пожалуйста , как решить задачу

Tags: python

Сегодня в магазине акция! Если цена товара является четным числом, вы получаете товар бесплатно!

Используйте список для сохранения цен на все товары в корзине.
Имеющийся код использует цикл while для итерации списка, вычисляет цену всех товаров в списке и выводит результат.

Измените код, чтобы пропустить нечетные цены, вычислить сумму только четных цен и вывести результат.

items = [23, 555, 666, 123, 128, 4242, 990]

Comment: Покажите код из задания, приложите ваши попытки решения, укажите с чем у вас возникают сложности при решении этой задачи

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно проверить каждое число в списке на чётность при помощи `items[i] % 2` (Остаток от деления)

Если число нечётное (Остаток не = 0) прибавляй к какой-нибудь переменной

Comment: на данном сайте не принято отвечать на вопросы-домашки, т.е. те задания, где человек не пытался решить проблему